# An error in unity with package manager UI

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, package

I just worked on my project and then this came up:

An error occurred while resolving packages:
Project has invalid dependencies:
com.unity.package-manager-ui: Package [com.unity.package-manager-ui@2.1.2] cannot be found

A re-import of the project may be required to fix the issue or a manual modification of C:/Users/idajac/test 4/Packages/manifest.json file.

Unde this alot of error come up like:
GUID [d3b47ff860a51904395688d633cb1018] for asset 'Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Editor/ShaderGraph/Templates/BuildSurfaceDescriptionInputs.template.hlsl' conflicts with:
'Packages/com.unity.shadergraph/Editor/Generation/Templates/BuildSurfaceDescriptionInputs.template.hlsl' (current owner)
We can't assign a new GUID because the asset is in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

---

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.3.1\Editor\ShaderGraph\SubShaders\UniversalPBRSubShader.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.3.1\Editor\ShaderGraph\SubShaders\UniversalSpriteLitSubShader.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.3.1\Editor\ShaderGraph\SubShaders\UniversalSpriteUnlitSubShader.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

Any help would be appreciated

(I'm using HDRP of it helps)

Comment: In the past Unity has had issues with spaces in directory names. You might try renaming the directory to remove the space. You could also delete the Library/PackageCache directory so it will download and reimport the packages.

Comment: Could you explain how I do that? I'm not quite sure how to

Comment: Should i just delete the whole file? Is it going to download it again without me having to do anything and what will the happen to the things I already have in my game?

Comment: Everything in the Library directory will be recreated if it is missing when you open the project. It's a temporary cache.

Comment: for some reason it seems I can't delete it, is there any other way?

Comment: You need to close Unity first. I'd suggest renaming the directory with a space in it first.

Comment: I have unity closed but my computer says I need permission from myself to close it  and I can't give it

Comment: It didn't work, it says the same thing again, should I delete manifest in the packages folder?